# Make a bootable cd from a floppy

Tags: kernel, compact-disc, floppy, qemu

I have followed this tutorial http://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_bones to build a simple C kernel and boot it successfully. But, how to convert the floppy image to CD image to use it with my real PC?

Comment: Most CD burning programs support a method for turning a floppy image into a bootable CD. What OS are you using, and what CD burning software do you have?

Comment: OS X .. but I have ubuntu and windows installed on other machines too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have converted all my old boot floppies to bootable CD's using Nero on a Windows box.

> First Of All You Need A Cd-Burner, Nero Burning Rom v5.5 or higher
>       A Floppy Drive, A Blank CDR Disk 
>       When You Have Everything:
>
> With Your Floppy In The Drive And Blank CD In The CD-Recorder
>
> Load Up Nero With Your Floppy In The Drive And Blank Cd In The Cd-Recorder 
>   Close The Wizard 
>   Hold Ctrl + N 
>   Until A Box Appears 
>   Scroll Down The List Until You Reach CDROM (Boot) 
>   Click It 
>   Bootable Logical Drive Must Be "A:" 
>   Click The Burn TAB 
>   Click New 
>   Click File- add files from A: 
>   Then Write CD

Answer (score 0):

The method for booting floppies and CD's are completely different. What you need is a [El Torito CD Image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Torito_%28CD-ROM_standard%29).

The only way that I know to create a bootable CD from scratch, is to use something like [IsoLinux](http://syslinux.zytor.com/wiki/index.php/ISOLINUX)

Answer (score 0):

The method for booting floppies and CDs are remarkably similar.  An El Torito CD is bootable because it contains the image of a bootable floppy disk,  separate from the main data on the disc.  Most good CD burning programs should have an option to use the floppy image to make the disc bootable.  For example, in Roxio on Windows, on the screen where you add files to disc, there's a "Make Bootable" button.  Clicking that will result in it asking you for the floppy image.

Similarly, in ImgBurn on Windows, in Build mode, select the "Advanced" tab, and the "Bootable Disc" tab under that.  Point the Boot Image field to your floppy image.